# connect lambda to another vpc via an EC2 vpn tunnel

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, ssh-tunnel

We have 2 separate VPC's and dont need to do any peering. one VPC has an openvpn software running for vpn purposes and a lambda in another vpc that needs access to the resource in the openvpn VPC. so how can this be done if we try to create a tunnel from an EC2 instance running in the Lambda's VPC that is connected to the other VPC via vpnclient? Would this work in this scenario or are there any other alternatives. The Lambda would like to reach the elasticsearch service running in the other VPC via VPN client running in the EC2 instance

Answer (score 0):

Please create VPC peering between these 2 VPCs & configure route tables of both.

In case of need further help, please do let me know

Comment: oh i just edited my post. we cannot create peering between 2 vpc's right now since that would give more easy access to full subnet. its just that we would like to use an ec2 that will have vpn client connect to this subnet and lambda going through this EC2 only with port forwarding between required ports.

Comment: Suraj- you can add Network access control list (NACL) and EC2 SG to reduce to single ip instead of open to all

Comment: mhh if we do vpc peering and since this will be a lambda function that will access the service, single ip block or restriction is not an option i think

Comment: @Suraj- Please go through https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-dedicated-vpc/  it will help you to resolve your problem